# How does changing the property value of an HTML element cause the change of the attribute value and vice versa?

Tags: javascript, dom

I used to think that changing an HTML element's attribute value will cause the property value to change, but changing the property value will NOT cause the attribute to change, because the attribute is like a blueprint as described by the HTML, and the property is the "live data".

But it turned out that, using plain JavaScript, if we change the property value, the attribute value is changed too.  Although in general, property value can be any data type, such as string, boolean, or object, while an attribute value should only be a string.  And the other difference is that attribute names are case-insensitive, but property names are case-sensitive. (as described in JavaScript Definitive Guide 6th edition, p. 375 - 376).

I tried it in:
http://jsfiddle.net/5nBM3/1/

and http://jsfiddle.net/5nBM3/2/ where it sets the property value, and in http://jsfiddle.net/5nBM3/3/ where it sets the attribute value.

If we sets the attribute value by using:

```
el.setAttribute("src", "http://i.imgur.com/4rE6FHV.gif");
```

then clearly, inside of `setAttribute()`, it can adjust the property value as well.  But if we set the property value by using:

```
el.src = "http://i.imgur.com/4rE6FHV.gif";
```

so if we consider it just like `obj.x = 1`, then it should not cause anything else to change.  How does the line above cause the attribute value to change as well?  Is it by

1. the object setter and getter function as in ECMA-5 (and in some ECMA-3 implementation) similar to the situation that if an object only has property `x` and `y`, we can define a setter and getter `r` for the radius, and use it as `a = obj.r` or `obj.r = 3`, so that getting the radius will invoke a function to calculate it using `x` and `y`, and setting `r` will invoke a function to adjust the values of `x` and `y` according to the new `r`, or
2. some observer model so that attribute observes the changes of property value, and property observes the change of attribute value, or
3. we can consider it just a black box or "magic", that the client-side JavaScript always maintain the value equivalence between a property and an attribute?

Comment: I've run into a related issue in the past. The property and attribute 'checked' appears not to be synchronised for checkbox inputs. Chrome, windows, v29. If you set the checked attribute to 'true' in the html, the checkbox is displayed in the checked state. However, the attribute is not changed when you click the box, though the property checked is!